# the filter_menu option of the pyvis diagram does not work with streamlit

Tags: html, streamlit, pyvis

When I tried to load a html file of an pyvis graph and when i render with `filter_menu = True` option, it doesn't rendedr the graph leaving just the blank background.

But the graph.html work perfectly without opening inside the streamilit.
[pyvis streamlit filter_menu does not render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy03h.jpg)

A solution or any tweaks to the setting that i can use to render the html pyvis graph properly.

Particular code for generating the plot

```
node_degree = dict(G.degree())

node_degree

net = Network(notebook = True ,
              width = '100%',
              height = '1000px',
              bgcolor  = '#222222',
              font_color = 'white',
              filter_menu=True) # bgcolor  = '#222222', font_color = 'white')

nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_degree , 'size')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, event_level1_dict,'group')

net.from_nx(G)
net.show_buttons()
net.show('witcher2.html')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually after passing some kwargs on the Network object of pyvis was able to get filter_menu to appear on streamlit as well as jupyter notebook

**cdn_resources='remote'**

```
net = Network(notebook = True ,width = '100%',height = '1000px',bgcolor ='#222222',font_color = 'white',filter_menu=True,cdn_resources='remote')

node_degree = dict(G.degree())

node_degree

net = Network(notebook = True ,
              width = '100%',
              height = '1000px',
              bgcolor  = '#222222',
              font_color = 'white',
              filter_menu=True,
             cdn_resources='remote') # bgcolor  = '#222222', font_color = 'white')

nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_degree , 'size')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, event_level1_dict,'group')

net.from_nx(G)
net.show_buttons()
net.show('witcher2.html')
```